# On Mouse Over doesn't fire triggers in ContentTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have some textboxes and I want to change some of their properties when I put the mouse over them. In this case, I want to change the BorderBrush and BorderThickness.

This is my XAML ControlTemplate, it's inside a `Window.Resource` tag:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border
                      Name="Border"
                      Padding="4"
                      BorderBrush="#ccc"
                      BorderThickness="1">
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFC4C4C4" Offset="0.0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFF8F8F8" Offset="0.10" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

This piece of code should set the properties I wrote inside the `Trigger` tag when the mouse cursor is over the textbox:

```
                   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

But this trigger simply don't get fired. Nothing happens.
Why? And how can I achieve this?

Comment: There's no point in prefixing questions with tags. There's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify border element name

```
<Trigger  Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" >
  <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"></Setter>
  <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"></Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, add the Value property to your trigger and set it to true. Also need to add the target name to tell it to change the properties of border which is in your control template.

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" >
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Border" Value="1"></Setter>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="Orange"></Setter>
</Trigger>
```